# How to set-up VPN chaining

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel

I have a machine with 2 VPN clients:

1. ExpressVPN, using OpenVPN, set to connect to a server in country A.
2. Wireguard, set to connect to a server in country B.

Currently, both configurations / clients are unaware of each other's existence.

Is there a way to create a tunnel to server 1 / country A, and *from there* a tunnel to server 2 / country B?

The desired end result should be, that, as far as traffic to server 2 is concerned, it comes from server 1 / country A, and as far as traffic to the internet is concerned, it comes from server 2 / country B?

I think this is called VPN chaining.

What's not working, is simply creating tunnel (1) first, and some time later tunnel (2) - then, no traffic to the internet is possible at all.

> Hmmm… your Internet access is blocked
>
> Firewall or antivirus software may have blocked the connection.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking firewall and antivirus configurations
>
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED

It's not just a DNS issue; directly using an IP address (e.g. https://140.82.113.3/ for github) does also not work.

I have full control over the configuration of both clients, as well as the setup/config of server 2. What I lack is knowledge/competence, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

The Wireguard config currently looks like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxx
Address = 10.6.0.7/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
MTU = 1420

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
PresharedKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = xxx:51820
```

Comment: It's more like "nesting". You'll need to pay extra attention to the routes used for 1. Non-encapsulated traffics 2. Encapsulated WG trafffics (with the non-encapsulated traffics within) 3. Encapsulated OVPN traffics (with encapsulated WG traffics within) respectively.

Comment: In other words, your default route should use the WG tunnel interface, your route for the WG endpoint should use the OVPN tunnel interface, and your route for the OVPN "remote" address should use a physical NIC.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan for your comment. I should be able to implement these suggestions all on the client side, is that correct? I don't know much about networking specifically. I've added the WG config to the question.

Comment: `I should be able to implement these suggestions all on the client side` Yes, otherwise it's probably better to actually chain instead (i.e., set up the opvn server as the wg client).

Comment: I have no control over the openvpn server, so that's not an option. Could you maybe tell me, how to change the wireguard config? Or point me to a helpful resource? I'm struggling with the terminology

Comment: Are you on Linux though? (I don't quite have an idea on how it should be configured on other OSes, if it is possible at all.)

Comment: The WG server is on linux. The client can run both Windows and Linux, so have your pick :) I think they use the same text configuration files anyway

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add something like this under the `[Interface]` section of the so-to-speak-client-side wg-quick conf:

```
PreUp = ip route add xxx dev tun0
PostDown = ip route delete xxx dev tun0
```

where `xxx` is the IP address in `Endpoint=`. Note that this will work only if you are using wg-quick on Linux, as it's running "external" program (`ip`) that is Linux-specific.

---

The reason why you need (only) the above is that, wg-quick performs some "tricks" when a peer is set to work as a default gateway, i.e., it makes use of policy routing and an extra route table to avoid adding / changing the effective default route in the `main` route table. In addition, one of the tricks also make sure that traffics for destinations covered by non-default routes in `main` will not be routed into the WireGuard tunnel.

Normally when you connect to a "commercial" OpenVPN, because of its purpose it will push / have in the client conf the `redirect-gateway` option, which will cause a host route for the server's remote address to be added to the (`main`) route table to avoid routing loop. Then it replace the original default route (which uses a physical NIC) with one that uses the tunnel interface it has created (which may not may not be `tun0`; check with e.g. `ip link` and adjust the above accordingly).

Since the default route in the `main` route table will be ignored when the WireGuard is up, so you will end up being with:

1. Traffics for the Internet (more precisely, destinations covered only by the default route in the `main` route table) will routed into the WireGuard tunnel
2. WireGuard-encapsulated traffics which has the destination of the address in `Endpoint=` will be routed into the OpenVPN tunnel because of the route added with the command given above
3. OpenVPN-encapsulated traffics which has the destination being the remote address in the OpenVPN conf will be routed out of the physical NIC which was originally used for the default route

Note that this implies that you must have the OpenVPN up first. Whenever its tun interface (e.g. `tun0`) is gone, the route added by the command above would be gone, which means you will need to either run it (the one in `PreUp=`) again manually or restart wg-quick after the tun interface is recreated.

**NOTE: often you'll get `redirect-gateway` pushed / in the conf given with the `def1` flag, which will by nature invalidate one of the wg-quick trick. The result is that the WireGuard tunnel will not be used at all. So make sure you get rid of the flag, and obviously, as usual, a what-is-my-ip test should tell you whether things are working as you like. (Well, I mean, whether you are at least using the WireGuard server as your Internet gateway.) Also, matter regarding DNS was not considered when this answer was written.**

---

For the record, even if this should technically work, there might be other factors (MTUs, maybe?) that prevent it from working or working as nicely as you desire. Also don't expect such setup to give you really decent performance or stability.